# Sorting numerical data in ascending order

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to sort data from data.txt file in ascending order, but I don;t seem to be able to find a solution - any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
input_file = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt') 
for line in input_file:
    print line

def insertion_sort(line):
    for i in range(0, len(line)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and line[j] < line[j-1]:
            line[j] = line[j-1] 
            j = j-1
insertion_sort (input_file)
print 'After sorting:', input_file
```

Comment: Try debugging line by line, add a print statement in the loop to see what's happening at each step. You may be surprised. Also, what's the error/exception? Maybe you are incorrectly handling the first element.

Answer (score 0):

After loading your file into a list, try using the list sort method for Lists : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_sort.htm 
 
and then rewrite your new sorted list into the text file.